# dynamically add fields and compute sum

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

i wanted to know how to compute the sum of all fields that are dynamically added and display the result in the page but i got lost in the way.

here is the code i am trying to review and learn:

thank you in advance ^__^

i need to know what to do next so i can add it to this one.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <title></title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>

<body>

<div class="field_wrapper">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="prc" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">add field</a>
    </div>
    
</div>
<div class="form-group">
      <output id="result"></output>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button">remove field</a></div>'; //New input field html 
    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
    
    
    //Once add button is clicked
    $(addButton).click(function(){
        //Check maximum number of input fields
        if(x < maxField){ 
            x++; //Increment field counter
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); //Add field html
        }
    });
    
    //Once remove button is clicked
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
        x--; //Decrement field counter
    });


});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

any help is very much appreciated. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming input number is integer:

```js
//Once add button is clicked
$(addButton).click(function(){
    //Check maximum number of input fields
    if(x < maxField){ 
        x++; //Increment field counter
        $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); //Add field html
        calculate_sum();
    }
});

//Once remove button is clicked
$(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
    x--; //Decrement field counter
    calculate_sum();
});

function calculate_sum() {
     let sum = 0;
     $('.field_wrapper').find('input.prc').each((index, element) => {
         sum += parseInt(element.value);
     });
     $('#result').text(sum);
}
```

Don't forget to add class `prc` to input in variable `fieldHTML`.
I also would suggest you to change `input type="text"` to `input type="number"`